# Reset all icons to default using CandyBar

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

Hello Im running [CandyBar3](http://www.panic.com/candybar/).  I was wondering if you guys knew of a way to return to the regular default osx icons from within CandyBar?

Running the latest version of all software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either click the button *Restore Icons* on the top right, or select *Restore Icons...* in the *Change* menu of Candybar. Do this once for every category.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I deleted and then downloaded Candybar again and I deleted my icons because I thought it would change something. It didn't.

All I did was add a random icon to an application (wanted to change iTunes icon) so I restored each icon one by one and that did the trick. To restore the picture above/below will help.